# Remove nodes that don't contain their own text using Jsoup

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I notice a lot of web pages have superfluous (for my purposes) html nodes. I'd like to remove them from the page, as it would make my processing a lot easier.

Is there a way to do it with JSoup?

To make the situation more clear, let's say we have the following page:

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>I have some text</div>
    <div class='useless'>
      <div class='useless'>
        <div>I also have text
          <div>I also have text</div>
        </div>
      </div>   
    </div>      
  </body>
</html>
```

I'd like to remove the class='useless' divs - but of course I can't select them by their class/id/tag etc only by the fact that they have no content. This will of course change the structure of the page, that's totally fine - it will make my final processing easier.

The result would be:

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>I have some text</div>
    <div class='useless'>
      <div class='useless'>
        <div>I also have text
          <div>I also have text</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>   
  </body>
</html>
```

Is this possible in an easy or hard way.

The result would be:

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>I have some text</div>
    <div>I also have text
      <div>I also have text</div>
    </div>  
  </body>
</html>
```

Right now I can't think of anything particularly elegant. My general inclination is to check the `ownText()` method on the various elements (will check `ownText().length() > 0`) and if `false` try to remove them, but I think that will remove any sub/child elements as well, even if they match `true` for an `.ownText()` condition.

Comment: With your `ownText().length() > 0` rule the `html`, `head` and `body` tags should also be removed, or am I wrong?

Comment: For my case it doesn't matter if we remove the `html` and `body` tags. The method you've described of appending tags that do contain text is perfect for what I need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Document.getAllElements()` and check each element if it has `ownText()`. If it has do nothing. If not, append all children to the parent node if there is one. This should do the job:

```
Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
document.getAllElements().stream()
        .filter(e -> e.ownText().isEmpty())
        .filter(Element::hasParent)
        .forEach(e -> {
            e.children().forEach(e.parent()::appendChild);
            e.remove();
        });
```

The result of the code you shared will be this:

```html
<div>
 I have some text
</div>
<div>
 I also have text 
 <div>
  I also have text
 </div> 
</div>
```

As I mentioned in the comments with your `ownText()` rule the `html`, `head` and `body` element should be also removed.

---

If you want to prevent some *special* tags from being removed you can use a simple `Set` or `List` which contains the tag names, which should be retained:

```
Set<String> retainTagNames = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("html", "body"));
Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
document.getAllElements().stream()
        .filter(e -> ! retainTagNames.contains(e.tagName()))
        .filter(e -> e.ownText().isEmpty())
        .filter(Element::hasParent)
        .forEach(e -> {
            e.children().forEach(e.parent()::appendChild);
            e.remove();
        });
```

The result of this will be:

```html
<html>
 <head> 
 </head> 
 <body> 
  <div>
   I have some text
  </div>   
  <div>
   I also have text 
   <div>
    I also have text
   </div> 
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```